# Removing a mySQL database without password?

Tags: mysql, debian, database, password, debian-jessie

So about 6 months ago I set up a wheezy server and at the same time I installed MySQL even though I didn't need it.

I've now updated to Jessie and need the database but can not remember the password as I made it rather secure. I thought I wrote it down somewhere but can not find it *sigh*. This is rather a noob thing to do and I am quite embarrassed by it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: do you mean [resetting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) root password

Comment: @qwillie yes that is what I mean.
When using the link you [provided](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix) and trying to start using mysql_safe I get `joseph@192:~$ sudo mysql_safe --init-file=/home/joseph/mysql-init &
[1] 10629
joseph@192:~$ sudo: mysql_safe: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an app connected to it, the password should be stored in a config file. Usually other parts of the system depending on what you are running will store the password in plain text. I would also try opening phpmyadmin possibly your browser saved the password and you can export the data that way.